# datepicker beforeShowDay dont add class on disabled calendar

Tags: jquery, datepicker

i have disabled datepicker calendar just for show unavailable dates and an array with unavailable dates

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var dates = ['01/03/2015','03/01/2015'];

$('#my_div').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: [2,2],
    showButtonPanel: false,
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+1Y',
    firstDay: 1,
    closeText: 'Chiudi',
    prevText: '&#x3c;Prec',
    nextText: 'Succ&#x3e;',
    currentText: 'Oggi',
    monthNames: ['Gennaio','Febbraio','Marzo','Aprile','Maggio','Giugno','Luglio','Agosto','Settembre','Ottobre','Novembre','Dicembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Gen','Feb','Mar','Apr','Mag','Giu','Lug','Ago','Set','Ott','Nov','Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domenica','Luned&#236','Marted&#236','Mercoled&#236','Gioved&#236','Venerd&#236','Sabato'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom','Lun','Mar','Mer','Gio','Ven','Sab'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do','Lu','Ma','Me','Gio','Ve','Sa'],
    isRTL: false,
    beforeShowDay: function (date){
        var year = date.getFullYear(), month = date.getMonth(), day = date.getDate();
        for (var i=0; i < dates.length; ++i)
            if (year == dates[i][2] && month == dates[i][1] - 1 &&  day == dates[i][0] - 1) 
                return [false, 'ui-state-highlight ui-state-active gior-occ'];
        return [false];
                                }
                    });

                        });
```

but when I see result on a date in array it return not my class gior-occ but undefined

```
<td class=" ui-datepicker-week-end ui-datepicker-unselectable ui-state-disabled undefined">
    <span class="ui-state-default">
        1
    </span>
</td>
```

Someone know why?

Comment: for complete html code see here
http://disign.it/test2.html

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts). BTW, it's "Thanks in advance", not "Thanks in advanced".

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to simply compare the date string with the date array strings, you can do this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var dates = ['01/03/2015', '03/01/2015'];

  $('#my_div').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
    numberOfMonths: [2, 2],
    showButtonPanel: false,
    changeMonth: false,
    changeYear: false,
    minDate: 0,
    maxDate: '+1Y',
    firstDay: 1,
    closeText: 'Chiudi',
    prevText: '&#x3c;Prec',
    nextText: 'Succ&#x3e;',
    currentText: 'Oggi',
    monthNames: ['Gennaio', 'Febbraio', 'Marzo', 'Aprile', 'Maggio', 'Giugno', 'Luglio', 'Agosto', 'Settembre', 'Ottobre', 'Novembre', 'Dicembre'],
    monthNamesShort: ['Gen', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'Mag', 'Giu', 'Lug', 'Ago', 'Set', 'Ott', 'Nov', 'Dic'],
    dayNames: ['Domenica', 'Luned&#236', 'Marted&#236', 'Mercoled&#236', 'Gioved&#236', 'Venerd&#236', 'Sabato'],
    dayNamesShort: ['Dom', 'Lun', 'Mar', 'Mer', 'Gio', 'Ven', 'Sab'],
    dayNamesMin: ['Do', 'Lu', 'Ma', 'Me', 'Gio', 'Ve', 'Sa'],
    isRTL: false,
    beforeShowDay: function(date) {
      if ($.inArray($.datepicker.formatDate('dd/mm/yy', date), dates) != -1) {
        return [false, 'ui-state-highlight ui-state-active gior-occ'];
      } else {
        return [false, ''];
      }
    }

  });

});
```

```css
.gior-occ {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.9.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="my_div" />
```

Note the yellow background color for the dates in question.